# How to Create a UIButton with Gradient and Highlighting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I am trying to create a UIButton with a gradient background. I got that work fine but the button does not highlight (default behavior is for the button to darken) when selected.

here's my button:

```
-(UIButton *)createLoginButtonForSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIButton *loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    loginButton.titleLabel.text = @"Login";

    [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [loginButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[loginButton(WIDTH)]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:@{@"WIDTH": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.width]}
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loginButton)]];

    [loginButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[loginButton(HEIGHT)]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:@{@"HEIGHT": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.height]}
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loginButton)]];

    CAGradientLayer *layer = [UIColor greenGradient];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer.cornerRadius = 8;

    [loginButton.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];

    return loginButton;
}
```

Do I need to handle the highlighting myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will need to handle highlighting yourself. Rather than rolling your own code though, you should check out Jeff Lamarche's incredibly easy to use [iPhone Gradient Buttons Project](http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/). It does exactly what you are trying to do. It's just 2 files, so it's easy to incorporate into your project:

http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/source/browse/trunk/Classes/GradientButton.h
http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/source/browse/trunk/Classes/GradientButton.m

Screenshot below taken from [Jeff's Blog discussing the project](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/improved-gradient-buttons.html).

[image: Imageless gradient buttons]